# Suggested way of doing cryptography using Common Lisp

Tags: cryptography

I was looking at the available cryptography libraries in Common Lisp (https://www.cliki.net/cryptography). Ironclad puts together most of them, but on the front page there is a big warning "Ironclad should not be considered safe against side-channel attacks".

Are there any better alternatives to Ironclad?

I have also looked at cl+ssl, but it uses a socket for the communication, are they safe? Couldn't someone else on the same PC have access to the IPC?

The only alternative I could come up with is using CFFI and use some libraries in C, is there a better approach?

My current use case is issuing and verifying JOSE (JSON Object Signing and Encryption).

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Please detail what cryptography operations you want to run (for instance: verifying the signature of a file, or reading from an HTTPS URL). Thanks!

Comment: The current use case is issuing and verifying JOSE

Comment: JSON Object Signing and Encryption? Please add that info to the question, as comments get deleted. Thanks! :-)